# Is there a way to change the accelerometer reference on an iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, core-motion

I am working on a SpriteKit game that uses CMMotionManager to move an object based on the accelerometer and gyro data. Currently it works great if I test the app and I have the device flat in my hands while I am sitting down or standing. However if one is laying down so the device isn't flat, but rather tilted on the x axis(in landscape mode) from the start, the object moves to the bottom and since the reference is so far off there is no way to move the object and play the game. So I am curious how, if it is possible, to detect that the device is not laying flat and adjust the accelerometer/gyro reference points accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can store a copy of the Attitude at start time and use it later as a reference to calculate the movement:

```
class MotionManagerSingleton {

    let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
    var referenceAttitude: CMAttitude?

    override init()  {
         motionManager = CMMotionManager()
         motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.25
         motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates()
         calibrate()
    }

    func calibrate() {
        referenceAttitude = motionManager.deviceMotion?.attitude.copy() as? CMAttitude
    }

    func getMotionVector() -> CGVector {
        // Motion
        let attitude = motionManager.deviceMotion?.attitude;

        // Use start orientation to calibrate
        attitude!.multiplyByInverseOfAttitude(sharedInstance.referenceAttitude!)

        return CGVector(dx: attitude!.pitch, dy: attitude!.roll)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your calibrate function causes a crash because `motionManager.deviceMotion?.attitude` is nil and then when I call getMotionVector it force unwraps a nil value here `sharedInstance.referenceAttitude!`

Comment: Sorry, this was only a subset of the whole stuff. I've written a blog post about this some time ago: http://developerplayground.net/?p=19